# A questionon FOR JSON to delegate the JSON formatting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json

The following statement retrieves data from a ODATA Service in SQL Server 2016 when the database context is set to AdventureWorks2014:

```
 SELECT 'http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products(ProductID,ProductName)/$entity' 
AS '@odata.context', ProductID, Name as ProductName   
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE ProductID <400
FOR JSON AUTO
```

When the 'master' is the context, it returns an error.
However, Northwind is not present in the SQL Server 2016 but on an Instance of SQL Server 2012 on the same Windows 10 machine.

Why did it work when the database context for running the query was 'AdventureWorks 2014'?

The above query is from this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If **master** is current database, this query will try to find Production.Product  table in the master database and it will fail because there is no such kind of table there.
You should switch context of the query to the database where table is placed, or use three part name with explicit database name, e.g.:

```
SELECT 'http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products(ProductID,ProductName)/$entity' 
AS '@odata.context', ProductID, Name as ProductName   
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Production.Product 
WHERE ProductID <400
FOR JSON AUTO
```